# Setting the margin-top of a div element appearing under a header with a fixed position,

Tags: jquery, header, position, margin, fixed

I have a header contained in a div wrapper entitled headerwrapper. The headerwrapper has a fixed position at the top of the screen. The height of the headerwrapper may vary as it contains elements that can flex in size.

The div that appears directly under the header is called albumimage. I want to set the margin-top of this div so that it sits directly under the header. As the header height can change I have tried the following jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  doResize();
  $(window).resize(doResize);
});

function doResize(){
var height = $('#headerwrapper').height();
$('#albumimage').css(margin-top, height);   
}
```

Relatively new at jquery but learning fast. Am guessing it's an obvious rookie mistake that someone can help me with...

Comment: Add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your example. That would make things easier.

Comment: Oh and... show us the css too...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I sorted the question. Simple error in code.